# When i download the excel file in php, A newline(0x0A) character is inserted at the first

Tags: php, excel, download, newline

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=test.xls");
    header("Cache-Control:max-age=0"); 

    echo 'test';


    // 'when i open the excel after download, A newline(0x0A) character have been inserted at the first character.'

    exit; 
?>
```

Here is code to write and download xsl file using php.

My problem occur when i open excel file.

A newline(0x0A) character is inserted at the first.

I want remove newline(0x0A) character.

help me. T_T

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFytz.jpg)

**[when i was opened the test.xls in the excel program]**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7DEU.jpg)

**[it has been converted hex code.]**

Comment: That code doesn't write any xsl (or even Excel file), it simply tells the web browser to expect an excel xls file, and then does absolutely nothing

Comment: yes, your right. contents is empty.
but, when i execute this, A newline(0x0A) character is inserted at the first. Even if there is content, it is the same :(

Comment: Please show more of your code. It can for example happen that a newline in an included php-file (before <?php or after ?>) becomes part of the output.

Comment: i was update my question. the sample code is just to download Excel. even though i only downloaded the Excel file, A newline(0x0A) character have been inserted at the first character.

Comment: That way you just produce a **text** file with the text test in it (and without any newline), **not** an Excel file. How Excel handles importing text files is another question, but it surely should not be named .xls.

Answer (score 0):

Like other developers pointed out in the comments you should post the whole code, but as I was facing the same problem, I will share with you what worked for me.

Search for ?> (php close tags) at config.php and other included files in you main code.

100% chance you have an extra line brake after a php close tag as I had here in my code. Remove it and you're good to go.

Example:

Main code: (index.php)

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
$some_file_path = '/var/www/html/image1.jpg';
$some_file_mime_type = 'image/jpeg';
$some_file_download_name = 'download.jpg';
$data_to_download = fread(fopen($some_file_path, 'r'), filesize($some_file_path));
header("Content-type: ".$some_file_mime_type);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$some_file_download_name\"");
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
header("Content-Encoding: none");
echo $data_to_download;
```

Config code: (config.php)

```
<?php
$some_code_config = 1;
?>
<!-- wipe out any space/chars/line-brakes you found here, including this comment -->
```

How your download would end up if you have extra chars at end of config file, after the php end tag:

[image: Image Download Error]